# Вынесение за пределы цикла

Tags: массивы, javascript, циклы

Не получается вынести template_list за пределы цикла.

```
var select = function(id, params, list) {
 var template_list = '';

 for(i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
  var key = list[i][0];
  var value = list[i][1];
  var template_list += key+' '+value;
 }

 alert(template_list); // не работает за пределами цикла
}
```

Comment: попробуйте убрать var перед template_list, который в цикле, вообще, если не ошибаюсь, то код вида:

    var varName += ...;

это синтаксическая ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var select = function(id, params, list) {
 var template_list = '';
 for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

  var key = list[i][0];
  var value = list[i][1];
     template_list +='key:'+ key+' value:'+value+ '; ';
 }

 alert(template_list); // не работает за пределами цикла
}
var list0=[[1,100],[2,200],[3,300],[4,400]];
select (1,'params',list0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AnrAx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, уберите `var` перед `template_list` в цикле. Используя ключевое слово `var` вы объявляете новую переменную в области видимости блока цикла, таким образом игнорируя `template_list`, объявленную в более общей области видимости.

Во-вторых, не `i <= list.length`, а `i < list.length`. Нумерация элементов массивов идёт с нуля и заканчивается `list.length - 1`. Таким образом, значение `list[length.list]` выходит за границы массива, и программа, пытаясь его прочитать выдаёт ошибку.

И в-третьих, научитесь пользоваться отладчиками JavaScript (Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, Opera Dragonfly). Они сразу напишут вам, какую ошибку вы допустили.

Comment: @fori1ton, уже лучше.

template_list = '';

 for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var key = list[i][0];
  var value = list[i][1];
  var template_list =+ key+' '+value;
 }
 
 $('body').append(template_list);

Но выводится только 1 элемент массива, а не все.

Comment: ****

    var template_list =+ key+' '+value; // вы серьезно? =+ ?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, что с ним, что без него, одно и тоже. И += не идет.